# Interactive Map: Send GeoServer WCS Request On Polygon Click

Tags: javascript, python, html, leaflet, geoserver

I have a vector grid over LeafLet.JS and I am in need to send a GeoServer WCS request to return the slice of the image that intersects the clicked cell grid or the slice formed by the parts of the images that intersects the clicked cell grid. Would   someone point me some directions, material, online resources  to achieve my goal?

Comment: what have you tried so far? what isn't working?

Comment: @IanTurton, I have not tried yet. But not sure if I should go with geoDjango or JavaScript. I mean, not sure if I should deploy back and frontend with geoDjango or run JavaScript to make the bridge between the frontend and GeoServer.